# Haskell: List comprehension predicate order

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

After reading about the Haskell syntax for List Comprehensions online, I got the feeling that predicates always come last. Eg:

```
[(x,y) | x <- [1..10000], y <- [1..100], x==2000, odd y]
```

But the following line accomplishes the same result:

```
[(x,y) | x <- [1..10000], x==2000, y <- [1..100], odd y]
```

Normally I would just take this as a hint that the order doesn't matter and be done with it. However this is a problem that comes from an old exam, and the answer to the problem says that while the results may be the same, the way in which they are computed *may* differ.

I'm assuming this is true but I can't find any information about it on the web. **So my question is**: How could the computations differ between the two list comprehensions and why? Are list comprehensions some form of syntactic sugar that I don't know about?

Comment: A good starting point https://wiki.haskell.org/List_comprehension

Comment: Your link gave me an idea to try this with infinite lists, and did yield results. `take 10 [(x,y) | x <- [1..10000], y <- [1..], x==2000, odd y]` never finishes while `take 10 [(x,y) | x <- [1..10000], x==2000, y <- [1..], odd y]` does.

Comment: For the desugaring of list comprehensions, see https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-420003.11

Comment: The [Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-420003.11) is the canonical, comprehensive resource for core language questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They differ in the way of how many intermediary results/lists are generated.

You can visualize this with some `trace` - note that I modified this a bit to give reasonable results - also I replaced the return values by `()` to make it clearer:

```
comprehension1 = [ () | x <- [1..3], trace' 'x' x, y <- [1..3], trace' 'y' y, x==2, odd y]
comprehension2 = [ () | x <- [1..3], trace' 'x' x, x==2, y <- [1..3], trace' 'y' y, odd y]

trace' :: Show a => Char -> a -> Bool
trace' c x = trace (c : '=' : show x) True
```

here is the evaluation:

```
λ> comprehension1
x=1
y=1
y=2
y=3
x=2
y=1
[()y=2
y=3
,()x=3
y=1
y=2
y=3
]
λ> comprehension2
x=1
x=2
y=1
[()y=2
y=3
,()x=3
]
```

now do you notice something?

Obviously in the first example every `(x,y)` pair for `x=1,2,3` and `y=1,2,3` is generated before the filters are applied.

But in the second example the `y`s are only generated when `x=2` - so you could say it's *better*/more performant

Comment: I didn't now trace could be used like that, thank you for that! It's also interesting that this isn't explicitly written anywhere, I can easily image falling into the trap of putting predicates last and ending up with a function that never finishes. Not only that, there seems to be significant difference in the number of computations performed.

Comment: I changed the definition a bit and I think you can see what's going on better now - but yeah you still have to think things through ;)

Comment: Using `trace' c x = trace (c : '=' : show x) True` and therefore `trace' 'x' x` and `trace' 'y' y` would make the lines a lot shorter and probably easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

You can think of a list comprehension like

```
[(x,y) | x <- [1..10000], y <- [1..100], x==2000, odd y]
```

as corresponding to the imperative pseudo-code

```
for x in [1..10000]:
    for y in [1..100];
        if x == 2000:
            if odd y:
                yield (x,y)
```

and

```
[(x,y) | x <- [1..10000], x==2000, y <- [1..100], odd y]
```

as corresponding to

```
for x in [1..10000]:
    if x == 2000;
        for y in [1..100]:
            if odd y:
                yield (x,y)
```

Specifically, passing the list comprehension to something like `mapM_ print` is the same operationally as replacing `yield` by `print` in the imperative version.

Obviously, it's almost always better to "float" a guard/`if` out of a generator/`for` when possible. (The rare exception is when the generator is actually an empty list, and the guard condition is expensive to compute.)